# How to test update with Apollo Client & Cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing, apollo-client

I've been doing some E2E tests with Cypress and in order to not rely on the external GraphQL API, it's necessary to apply stubs, intercepting the network calls, and returning responses as mocks.

Refer to the following command for intercepting GraphQL requests:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("graphqlOperations", () => {
  cy.intercept(
    "POST",
    "/graphql",
    (req) => {
      const { body: { operationName } } = req;

      req.alias = MAP_OPERATION_NAME_TO_ALIAS[operationName];

      Cypress.log({ message: { operationName } });
      Cypress.log({ message: { response: MAP_OPERATION_NAME_TO_MOCK[operationName] } });

      if (MAP_OPERATION_NAME_TO_MOCK[operationName]) {
        req.reply(MAP_OPERATION_NAME_TO_MOCK[operationName]);
      }
    },
  );
```

When updating an item from a list, Apollo Client already handles the cache re-invalidation and automatically re-fetches the query. But by re-fetching the query, the request is intercepted, and the mock is returned instead of returning the list with the item updated (cache re-invalidated).

This behavior happens perfectly with mutations that execute optimistic updates manually, in that way, the query isn't re-fetched and it returns directly the cache from the browser store.

This is the E2E test that I'm trying to implement for updating a recipe

```
it("Should update recipe", () => {
    const {
      response: {
        data: {
          recipe: {
            name,
          },
        },
      },
    } = createRecipeMock;

    cy.getByTestId(`recipe-${name}`).click();

    cy.fillForm(updateRecipeMock.formData).wait("@getRecipeQuery");

    cy
      .getByTestId(`recipe-${updateRecipeMock.formData.name}`)
      .should("exist")
      .wait("@updateRecipeMutation");
  });
});
```

Screenshots from the Cypress runner:

[image]
[image]

What's the best approach to handle this case?